# Java class with concrete type as parameter

Tags: java, generics

Is there any point in declaring a class with "concrete" types as generics?

If yes, what's the use for it?

If no, any specific reason why the compiler is allowing it?

The code:

```
public class SomeClass<Integer> {  

    //...

    public static void main (String a[]) {
        // SomeClass <> iSome = new SomeClass<>();
        // SomeClass <Integer> jSome = new SomeClass<>();

        SomeClass <Double> kSome = new SomeClass<>();

        // ...
    }
}
```

is running fine, and is giving compiler errors when I uncomment the lines declaring `iSome` and `jSome`.

I'm trying to put things together in "deciphering" the generics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not what you think. You're creating a generic type parameter called `Integer` which shadows `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: so "Integer" is not reserved there-- JVM isn't checking whether it's a class in java.lang and public class SomeClass<Integer> is quivalent to public class SomeClass<T>(?)

Comment: @Roam Yes, that's right. The name `Integer` is being shadowed by your generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In the class definition the parameter you called `Integer` could be also just be `T` without changing the sense.

AFIK you can omit the generic just in Java 7 where the compiler adds this automatically it is anyway not stored at runtime. So you must define the generic in a lefthand definition, the only exception of this is using the question mark which is used as a wildcard.

```
// here is the generic missing the compiler cannot guess it:
SomeClass<> iSome = new SomeClass<>();
// here does the compiler know that you want a Double
SomeClass<Double> jSome = new SomeClass<>();
// this will also work
SomeClass<?> kSome = new SomeClass<Boolean>();
```