# Issue with Generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I am facing one issue with generic implementation. Below is the code:

```
public interface Response<S, T> {

 public void response(S data, T... arg);
}

public class CustomerDetail<XYZ, PQR> implements Response<XYZ, PQR> {
  @Override
  public void response(XYZ data, PQR... args) {
    PQR request = args[0];
    Map reportMap = data.any();
    //do something
  }
}


public class EmployeeDetail<ABC, DEF> implements Response<ABC, DEF> {
  @Override
  public void response(ABC data, DEF... args) {
     List reportList = data.getDetails();
    //do something
  }
}
```

Also , class XYZ, ABC looks like below:

```
public class XYZ {
   public Map any() {
     //do something
     return mapObject;
  }
}

public class ABC {
   public List getDetails() {
     //do something
     return listObject;
  }
}
```

During compilation , i am getting the compilation error:

```
cannot find method any();
cannot find the method getDetails();
```

Earlier i tried with this code, and it was working fine:

```
public class CustomerDetail<S, T> implements Response<S, T> {
  @Override
  public void response(S data, T... args) {
    PQR request = (PQR)args[0];
    Map reportMap = ((XYZ)data).any();
    //do something
  }
}


public class EmployeeDetail<S, T> implements Response<S, T> {
  @Override
  public void response(S data, T... args) {
     List reportList = ((ABC)data).getDetails();
    //do something
  }
}
```

But i dont want the typecasting of generic variables. So i followed the above approach. I tried to follow the [link](https://support.rs.adobe.com/check_access_key?access_key=cc6d2782a36bce21d78b81d525ee9956) Any idea, where i am making mistake. Thanks

Comment: And what line of code was the compilation error on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java class with concrete type as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294095/java-class-with-concrete-type-as-parameter)

Comment: Inside `EmployeeDetail` and `CustomerDetail`, `XYZ` and `DEF` *don't* mean the classes, they mean the type parameters. This is why it's a bad idea to give the same name to different things.

Comment: You have asked 4 questions on this site, and accepted no answers. Please read about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and consider accepting answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you are shadowing classes with generic types.

This declaration (with superfluous `public` removed):

```
public interface Response<S, T> {
    void response(S data, T... arg);
}
```

Takes **any** types `S` and `T`, so this `class`:

```
public class CustomerDetail<XYZ, PQR> implements Response<XYZ, PQR> {
  @Override
  public void response(XYZ data, PQR... args) {
    PQR request = args[0];
    Map reportMap = data.any();
    //do something
  }
}
```

Merely redefines the generic type **variables** `S -> XYZ` and `T -> ABC`. You haven't specified concrete types here, you have merely defined generic type variables that happen to have the same name as your classes.

If you want a `class` to extend a **specific** generic type, it should not have type definitions:

```
public class CustomerDetail implements Response<XYZ, PQR> {
  @Override
  public void response(XYZ data, PQR... args) {
    PQR request = args[0];
    Map reportMap = data.any();
    //do something
  }
}
```

As a side note, as you are playing with generics, you should know that the definition of `List` is `List<E>` and the definition of `Map` is `Map<K, V>` - they're also generic. Don't use rawtypes.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes implementing the interfaces are not generics classes. So you should not provide parameters:

```
public class EmployeeDetail<ABC, DEF> implements Response<ABC, DEF> {
```

This makes a generic class `EmployeeDetail` with two parameters `ABC` and `DEF`. You mean to fill the parameters of the `Response` class.

Instead you should do the following:

```
public class EmployeeDetail implements Response<ABC, DEF> {
```

This indicates that `EmployeeDetail` fills the parameters of the `Response` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public class CustomerDetail<XYZ, PQR> implements Response<XYZ, PQR>
```

To:

```
public class CustomerDetail implements Response<XYZ, PQR>
```

And change:

```
public class EmployeeDetail<ABC, DEF> implements Response<ABC, DEF>
```

to:

```
public class EmployeeDetail implements Response<ABC, DEF>
```